# OpenSSL: convert from pfx with SANs intact

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I work at a place where the CA and all certificates are initially provided in .pfx format. I am able to successfully convert the pfx to key/pem or key/crt depending on my need. When testing this week, I discovered that the conversion process doesn't bring over the SANs that are on the certificates. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to manually configure a config file that includes the SANs? Here is what I'm doing now to convert from pfx:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <pfx> -out <key> -nocerts -nodes
openssl rsa -in <key> -out <key>
openssl pkcs12 -in <pfx> -out <pem> -nokeys -clcerts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Subject Alternative Name values are part of the certificate.  When you did your original pkcs12 operation you specified `-nocerts` so the certificates aren't emitted, just the key objects.

Since keys don't have SANs you've discarded the data at that step.  You need to keep the certificates around.